# Remove object from dictionary if a value is not found in an array

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to manipulate an array of dictionaries based on an array of values.

for example:

```
arrayOfDicts = 
(
        {
        caption = a;
        urlRep = "12";
    },
        {
        caption = b;
        urlRep = "34";
    },
        {
        caption = c;
        urlRep = "56";
    }
)
```

Array of values:

```
urlReps = (12,56);
```

outcome I am trying to achieve:

```
(
        {
        caption = a;
        urlRep = "12";
    },
        {
        caption = c;
        urlRep = "56";
    }
)
```

The code I have now that adds to it based on the array is this:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOfDicts;
NSMutableSet *urlReps;
[urlReps minusSet:[NSSet setWithArray:[arrayOfDicts valueForKey:@"urlRep"]]];

    // merge new dicts to the original array
    for (id urlRep in urlReps)
    {
        [arrayOfDicts addObject:@{ @"urlRep" : urlRep, @"caption" : @"" }];

    }
```

This adds to my array of dicts if there are more urls in the array but I need to also remove if there are less urls in the array compared to the dict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something Like this using NSPredicate to filter the array:

```
NSArray *arrayOfDicts = .... //your existing data
NSArray *filteredURLParams = @[@"12",@"56"];

NSPredicate *urlPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"urlRep IN %@",filteredURLParams];    

NSArray *filteredDicts = [arrayOfDicts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:urlPredicate];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some old fashioned, straightforward, and completely untested code :-)

```
// Your data
NSMutableArray* arrayOfDicts = [...];
NSMutableSet* urlReps = [...];

// Will receive those dictionaries that have a matching urlRep 
NSMutableArray* filteredArrayOfDicts = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];

// Initially contains all urlReps, but we will successively
// eliminate those urlReps that we encountered
NSMutableSet* urlRepsNotSeen = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:0];
[urlRepsNotSeen addObjects:[urlReps allObjects]];

for (NSDictionary* dict in arrayOfDicts)
{
  NSString* urlRep = [dict valueForKey:@"urlRep"];
  if ([urlReps containsObject:urlRep])
  [
    [filteredArrayOfDicts addObject:dict];
    // Not sure what happens if urlRepsNotSeen does not contain the
    // urlRep (because we eliminated it earlier). If it crashes, add
    // this check:
    //   if ([urlRepsNotSeen containsObject:urlRep])
    [urlRepsNotSeen removeObject:urlRep];
}
arrayOfDicts = filteredArrayOfDicts;
for (NSString urlRepNotSeen in urlRepsNotSeen)
{
  [arrayOfDicts addObject:@{ @"urlRep" : urlRepNotSeen, @"caption" : @"" }];
}
```